# how to copy the text in textbox to 1 column of datagridview1?

Tags: c#, datagridview

How to copy the text box data into 1st column of datagridview1

```
try
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dg1.Rows)
    {

        dg1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = lblapplicantcode.Text;
    }
}
catch (exception ex)
{
}
```

Comment: You are only updating Row[0].Cells[0]

Comment: all iwant is the text from textbox paste to 1 column of datagridview

Comment: 5 row so it means 5paste. but i want it automatically, when the datagridview have row data

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dg1.Rows)
{
   row.Cells[0].Value = lblapplicantcode.Text;
}
```